# Bridging lxc vs virtualbox

Tags: virtualization, bridge, container

Something that is confusing me is the difference between "bridging" with a Virtualbox VM, and an lxc container.

When you start a start a VM, the VM creates a bridge ( apparently ) as a user.
Furthermore the bridge does not have an interface on the host system ( as evidenced by the lack of new entries in the table generated by the command ifconfig ). OTOH a bridge for LXC, must be created on the host as root ( typically called lxcbr0, or lxcbrX if there is more than one ).

Furthermore it seems that with the second mechanism, the bridge interface is more intrusive, limiting what a user networking on the host system can do.

Can someone please explain the differences ( and in particular how to bring 
LXC bridging closer to vbox bridging)?